# условие where для столбца, созданного аналитической функцией

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle

Имеется запрос, в котором создается столбец при помощи кода

```
count(1) over (partition by field_1) as MY_FIELD
```

Данный столбец затем используется в условии decode, которое возвращает нужные мне значения.

Однако, когда я в условии `where` пытаюсь прописать

```
where MY_FIELD <> 0
```

мне сообщается об ошибке:

> ora-00904 недопустимый идентификатор"

пытаюсь заменить `MY_FIELD` на `decode`, в котором содержится условие - возвращается ошибка:

> "Групповая функция здесь не разрешена"

Как можно поменять структуру запроса, чтобы он выполнялся корректно? При необходимости могу сбросить весь селект

Comment: Оформите его как подзапрос (ну или затолкайте в WITH), оберните запросом, в котором и выполните необходимый отбор.

Comment: Ещё можно оформить ваш запрос как виртуальную таблицу, использовав «WITH vtab as (...) select ... from vtab where MY_FIELD != 0

Comment: Оформил как подзапрос - все заработал как нужно. Благодарю!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас не получится в блоке `where` обращаться к вычисляемому полю из `select`, так как при выполнении запроса сначала идет фильтрация по условиям и потом применяются аналитические функции.
В Вашей ситуации можно обернуть запрос в еще один `select`. Выглядеть это будет примерно так:

```
select * 
from 
(
  select count(1) over (partition by field_1) as MY_FIELD,
         ....
  from table 
) t
where MY_FIELD != 0
```